# Directories with JavaScript files to be used by CGI binary aren't seen

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I have a CGI script named `check.cgi`. It uses JavaScript files from the directory `SCRIPTS` which is located in the same directory as `check.cgi`. I use Python's `CGIHTTPServer` as an embedded server which uses the directory with `check.cgi` as a current work-dir. If I want to call some script from the `SCRIPTS` dir I simply refer to it, eg, as `SCRIPTS/init.js`. Under Python's `CGIHTTPServer` everything works just fine! But then I want to place `check.cgi` file and `SCRIPTS` dir in Apache's `cgi-bin`. I access it as `localhost/cgi-bin/check.cgi` from within browser. The script is executed but it seems to unable to locate the `SCRIPTS` dir. Where should I place `SCRIPTS` dir so that my CGI script sees it?